# How to extract view meta data from tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I need to extract metadata from view. When I was reading tableau rest API documentation there is no ways mention in the rest api for sheet metadata and also not mention measure and dimension API extraction. If anyone knows the way how to extract data please help me

Comment: What are some examples of the content you are looking for?

Comment: measure and dimensions label and their processing

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Tableau Javascript API...specifically the getData method.

The Rest API is used for automating Tableau Server tasks (add users, create schedules, set permissions, etc).

Comment: I have already created that api in my node js code. I also found tableau workbook content rest api in documentation

Answer (score 0):

You can embed a hidden extension into your dashboard that can access worksheet, field and filter information. See the docs on extensions [here](https://github.com/tableau/extensions-api/).

[Here](https://github.com/TheInformationLab/Tableau-Extension-ExportData) is a good example of one that could get you started on pulling the worksheet and field information.

Comment: I have just want rest api like feature or any python or node js snippets

Answer (score -1):

Use the Tableau Metadata API - https://help.tableau.com/current/api/metadata_api/en-us/index.html

You can find sample scripts here - https://github.com/tableau/metadata-api-samples